# ionic display fullscreen image on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

i am building a mobile app using Ionic. Created a layout similar to this -->  [Card Layout](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-showcase)

How to show the card image on full screen when the image gets clicked by user and back to normal when clicked again.

Plese find the exisitng code below:
home-ctrl.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'collegeApi', '$ionicModal', HomeCtrl]);

function HomeCtrl($scope, collegeApi, $ionicModal) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.imgList = [
        {
            name: 'slider2.jpg'
    },
        {
            name: 'slider3.jpg'
    },
        {
            name: 'slider4.jpg'
    },
        {
            name: 'slider5.jpg'
    }];


    $scope.homeEvents = collegeApi.getHomeData();
    console.log($scope.homeEvents);



};
```

})();

home.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" ng-controller="HomeCtrl as vm">
<ion-content>
    <ion-slide-box>
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="img in vm.imgList">
            <img ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="full-image">
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>

    <div class="list card back-color" ng-repeat="homeEvent in homeEvents">

        <div ng-switch="homeEvent.type">
            <div ng-switch-when='star'>
                <div class="item item-icon-left item-energized">
                    <i class="icon ion-star light"></i>
                    <h2 class="light font-size-1">
           Header</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="event">
                <div class="item item-icon-left item-calm">
                    <i class="icon ion-android-calendar light"></i>
                    <h2 class="light font-size-1">
           Header</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="sport">
                <div class="item item-icon-left item-balanced">
                    <i class="icon ion-android-bicycle light"></i>
                    <h2 class="light font-size-1">
           Header</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-default>
                <div class="item item-icon-left item-dark">
                    <i class="icon ion-star light"></i>
                    <h2 class="light font-size-1">
          Header</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="item item-body">
            <img class="full-image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" ng-click="buttonClick('img/conference.jpg')">
            <p>
                <div class="text-justify" data-markdown="{{homeEvent.details}}"></div>
            </p>

        </div>
        <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
            <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                <i class="icon ion-share"></i> Share
            </a>
        </div>


    </div>



</ion-content>
```

Here is the screen shot :
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCc1G.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us your code? Or even better, create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/)?

Comment: Added the code and screen shot. Sorry i am new to stackoverflow. Unable to provide inline image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following these steps hope so this will help you

First use in your **.HTML**  file this script

```
 <script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
                        <div class="modal" ng-click="closeModal()">
                        <ion-content>
                        <img src="{{imgUrl}}" style="display:block; width:100%; max-width:600px; margin:auto"/>
                        </ion-content>
                        </div>
                    </script>
```

Second Use in Your Controller

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', function (modal) {
                $scope.gridModal = modal;
            }, {
                scope: $scope,
                animation: 'slide-in-up'
            })
            $scope.openModal = function (data) {
                $scope.inspectionItem = data;
                $scope.gridModal.show();
            }
            $scope.closeModal = function () {
                $scope.gridModal.hide();
            }
```

3rd Use in your CSS file

```
.modal .scroll {
height: 100% !important;
background-color: black !important;

display: -webkit-box !important;
display: -moz-box !important;
display: -ms-flexbox !important;
display: -webkit-flex !important;
display: flex !important;

-webkit-box-direction: normal !important;
-moz-box-direction: normal !important;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal !important;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal !important;
-webkit-flex-direction: row !important;
-ms-flex-direction: row !important;
flex-direction: row !important;


-webkit-box-align: center !important;
-moz-box-align: center !important;
-webkit-align-items: center !important;
-ms-flex-align: center !important;
align-items: center !important;
}
```

**Edited:**
Just Copy and paste the code into the files, and change the parameter of imgeURI to your image URL. The java script automatic call by id `modal.html` and on the image View click use

```
ng-click="openModal(imageUrl)"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. iadded the above code, but how the call the modal from image click.

Comment: Just Copy and paste the code into the files, and change the parameter of imgeURI to your image URL. 
The java script automatic call by id `modal.html`  and on the image View click use `ng-click="openModal(imageUrl)" `

Comment: Thanks a lot :-). It works. I also find a link providing similar solution [Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/rdelafuente/pen/tJrik/)

Comment: Great so now you can Approve my answer so that other guys can use that, and also do not forgot to check this answer(I think you have approved this but pending check).. Enjoy the ionic it's great platform to develop a open source application..

Comment: It's a good Solution. Though Can you explain what happens when we call this `openModal(imageUrl)` from inside a `$ionicModal` itself?

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution as per [APK APPS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6389464/apk-apps)

Here is the updated code:

My Controller :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'collegeApi', '$ionicModal', HomeCtrl]);

function HomeCtrl($scope, collegeApi, $ionicModal) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.imgList = [
        {
            name: 'slider2.jpg'
    },
        {
            name: 'slider3.jpg'
    },
        {
            name: 'slider4.jpg'
    },
        {
            name: 'slider5.jpg'
    }];


    $scope.homeEvents = [
        {
            type: 'star',
            name: 'Awesome'
    },
        {
            type: 'sport',
            name: 'Rocks'
    },
        {
            type: 'event',
            name: 'New event'
    },
        {
            type: 'other',
            name: 'Lorem'
    }];


    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', function (modal) {
        $scope.gridModal = modal;
    }, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    })
    $scope.openModal = function (data) {
        $scope.inspectionItem = data;
        $scope.gridModal.show();
    }
    $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.gridModal.hide();
    }

    };
})();
```

My HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" ng-controller="HomeCtrl as vm">
<ion-content>
    <ion-slide-box>
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="img in vm.imgList">
            <img ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="full-image">
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>

    <div class="list card back-color" ng-repeat="homeEvent in homeEvents">

        <div ng-switch="homeEvent.type">
            <div ng-switch-when='star'>
                <div class="item item-icon-left item-energized">
                    <i class="icon ion-star light"></i>
                    <h2 class="light font-size-1">
           Header</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="event">
                <div class="item item-icon-left item-calm">
                    <i class="icon ion-android-calendar light"></i>
                    <h2 class="light font-size-1">
           Header</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="sport">
                <div class="item item-icon-left item-balanced">
                    <i class="icon ion-android-bicycle light"></i>
                    <h2 class="light font-size-1">
           Header</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-default>
                <div class="item item-icon-left item-dark">
                    <i class="icon ion-star light"></i>
                    <h2 class="light font-size-1">
          Header</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="item item-body">
            <img class="full-image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" ng-click="openModal('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/')">
            <p>
                <div class="text-justify" data-markdown="{{homeEvent.details}}"></div>
            </p>

        </div>
        <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
            <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                <i class="icon ion-share"></i> Share
            </a>
        </div>


    </div>

    <script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <div class="modal" ng-click="closeModal()">
            <ion-content>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="display:block; width:100%; max-width:600px; margin:auto" />
            </ion-content>
        </div>
    </script>

</ion-content>
```

MY CSS:

```
.modal .scroll {
height: 100% !important;
background-color: black !important;
display: -webkit-box !important;
display: -moz-box !important;
display: -ms-flexbox !important;
display: -webkit-flex !important;
display: flex !important;
-webkit-box-direction: normal !important;
-moz-box-direction: normal !important;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal !important;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal !important;
-webkit-flex-direction: row !important;
-ms-flex-direction: row !important;
flex-direction: row !important;
-webkit-box-align: center !important;
-moz-box-align: center !important;
-webkit-align-items: center !important;
-ms-flex-align: center !important;
align-items: center !important;
}
```

Comment: If the answer of APK APPS helped you, don't forget to upvote it.

Comment: You will get there. :) Still you can accept one answer.